# How to properly free array of pthread_t in C?

Tags: c, pthreads, free

I have array of pthread_t in C like this.

```
pthread_t *workers;         // worker threads running tasks from queue
workers = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*workers_count)

// then I creates pthread by passing &workers[i] to pthread_create()
```

Now I am considering how should I free them. 
I done something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<workers_count; i++)
        free(workers[i]);
    free(workers);
```

But isn't pthread_t a struct that can contain some internal pointers that should be freed? Maybe there is some function pthread_destroy(pthread_t *)?

Comment: As long as you make sure to `pthread_join()` or `pthread_detach()` all of your threads, you can simply `free()` your `pthread_t*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But isn't pthread_t a struct that can contain some internal pointers
>   that should be freed?

You don't have to worry about the what `pthread_t` structure contains (or if it's even a `struct`) or how it's implemented. You (can) only `free()` what *you* allocated using `malloc()`, `calloc()`, etc.

> Maybe there is some function pthread_destroy(pthread_t *)?

There's no such function because there's no need for such a function.

So, unless you need the thread IDs later for any purpose (*joining*, sending signal using `pthread_kill()`, etc), what you do is fine. Otherwise, you need to make sure you free() at the appropriate point in your code (i.e. when the thread IDs are no longer needed).

---

I am not entirely sure how you allocate in your code. Here's a simple example with dynamic allocation of thread IDs which might clarify it a bit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* doSomeThing(void* arg)
{
    printf("From thread function: Thread ID: %ld\n", (long)pthread_self());
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t count = 10;
    pthread_t *tid;

    tid = malloc(count * sizeof *tid);

    for(size_t i = 0; i< count; i++) {
        int rc = pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, &doSomeThing, NULL);
        if(rc) { /* failure */ }
    }

    for(size_t i = 0;i<count; i++) {
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);
    }

    free(tid);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above example, I *join* with threads. Since, the thread IDs are needed for joining, I *free()* the `tid` after that.

Also, you can see I call `free()` just once because `tid` was allocated a block for 10 `pthread_t`'s. Basically, you call `free()` once for each call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`) and the the pointer you pass to `free()` must be the *same* that was previously returned by one of the `*alloc()` functions.

Comment: ok i think that free(thread_pool->workers); suffice as when I have additional for loop deallocation I am getting SIGABR exception

Comment: @MichałZiobro you have two different constructs in your code; a bare `workers` variable, and what *appears* to be a struct member `workers` in some instance `thread_pool`. That isn't exactly helping clarify things. None the less, PP is absolutely correct here (and definitely worthy of upticking). Only free the `workers` sequence, and that, only if it was dynamically allocated (which it appears to be in the first code list, unknown in the second). If all the threads should be finished before that, make sure to `pthread_join` on all of them before said-free (assuming they're joinable).

Comment: I edit it yeah workers array is inside thread_pool struct, but I am considering only deallocation of internal array workers not thread pool struct

Comment: 1) the compiler will output warning messages because of unused parameters `arg`, `argc` and `argv`,  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.